# Conditionally Highlight a Variable

Tags: mathcad

Is it possible to highlight a variable depending on its value?

e.g. automatically highlight this variable green:

```
variable = "acceptable"
```

but if it changes to:

```
variable = "unacceptable"
```

the highlight would change to red.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some sort of service to determine the sentiment from the data a variable contains.

For instance, I can easily call :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/

to determine the difference between "acceptable" and "unacceptable". In the link you can actually call the service with both the words and see that in first case, the result returns 98% sentiment while for the other one it returns 2%. You can use this value even generate a smooth range of rgb colors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to get exactly what you want but this might get you close

From the link:

> Export your results to an excel object and have that object displayed in your mathcad sheet may be a way.

Also:

> What you are looking for could be done in Mathcad 15 (and below) using scripted components - Text boxes. In Prime this feature is missing.

https://community.ptc.com/t5/PTC-Mathcad-Questions/Is-there-a-way-to-add-conditional-formatting/td-p/328451

Comment: **From Review** - This answer was flagged as **low quality**. While answers are always appreciated, please [**summarise your link's points**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) in your answer itself. The link to the page could [**break in the future**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), which might detract from your answer. In fact, answers that are little more than a link [**may be deleted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). A few sentences covering the key points from your link would make it so that your answer remains sound, even if the link no longer works :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have updated the answer with the relevant information from the link

Comment: @AaronRoberts Could you elaborate on that second option (scripted components)?